# Code is not compiling but seems good to me

Tags: excel, vba

This section of code should loop through the table of data in the column I tell it to, and if it is not 0 or blank it should copy the whole row of the table to another spreadsheet which is my formatted reports sheet.

This code seems good to me, and I have other similar pieces of code that work fine but this one does not for some reason.

```
Public Sub getActiveCodes()
 Dim tRows
 Dim i As Integer
 Dim ws As Worksheet, rpts As Worksheet
 Dim nxtRow As Integer
   Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
   Set rpts = Worksheets("REPORTS")
        For i = 1 To i = ws.Range("mainTable").Rows.Count
           nxtRow = Module1.countRows(rpts)
           If ws.ListObjects("mainTable").DataBodyRange(i, 9).Value <> 0_
  Or "" Then
             ws.ListObjects("mainTable").ListRows(i).Range.Copy
             rpts.Range("A:" & nxtRow).PasteSpecial , Paste:=xlPasteValues
           End If
        Next i
  End Sub
```

I would like this function to make a report of all data pertaining to each row item that is not zero in this column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cleaned up the code for you

```
Public Sub getActiveCodes()
Dim tRows
Dim i As Long, nxtRow As Long
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet, rpts As Worksheet

Set wb = Workbooks(REF)
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set rpts = wb.Worksheets("REPORTS")

For i = 1 To ws.Range("mainTable").Rows.Count
    nxtRow = Module1.countRows(rpts)
    If ws.ListObjects("mainTable").DataBodyRange(i, 9).Value <> 0 _ 
    Or ws.ListObjects("mainTable").DataBodyRange(i, 9).Value <> "" Then
        ws.ListObjects("mainTable").ListRows(i).Range.Copy
        rpts.Range("A:" & nxtRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Problem was your underscore and the general `If` statement. Before a line break, add a space. Moreover you shouldn't do `If x = 1 Or 2`, you should always include the value you compare it to, so `If x = 1 Or x = 2`. That is because `If x = 1 Or 2` reads as `if x = 1 is true or if 2 is true`, which will always be true because whether or not `x = 1`, there is nothing false about the number 2 on its own.

Using the `Copy` function to just copy values is slow. You're better off equalising the values of two ranges like `Range("A1:A20").Value = Range("B2:B21").Value`

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Somewhat oddly, `For i = 1 to i = ...` seems to be valid syntax. At least it isn't flagged as a syntax error when you do `Debug > Compile` in the editor.

Comment: @JohnColeman it doesn't execute though, not in the way OP expects

Comment: @JohnColeman but in `For i = 1 To i = ws.Range("mainTable").Rows.Count` the `i = ws.Range("mainTable").Rows.Count` should either be `True` or `False` so `-1` or `0` so it is the same as `For i = 1 To -1` or `For i = 1 To 0`. So not a syntax error but it will fail.

Comment: @TimStack Definitely an error (the comparison `i = ws.Range("mainTable").Rows.Count` is converted to an integer) but not a *syntax* error (which is somewhat surprising)

Comment: Thise line should not hava a comma: `rpts.Range("A:" & nxtRow).PasteSpecial , Paste:=xlPasteValues` • And `"A:" & nxtRow` is no valid address.

Comment: so im working on not using copy now and my for loop looks like this

Comment: For i = 1 To ws.Range("mainTable").Rows.Count
    nxtRow = Module1.countRows(rpts)
    If ws.ListObjects("mainTable").DataBodyRange(i, 9).Value <> 0 _
    Or ws.ListObjects("mainTable").DataBodyRange(i, 9).Value <> "" Then
            ws.Range("mainTable").ListRows(i) = rpts.Range("A:" & nxtRow)

Comment: but it says method not found

Comment: 'method range of object worksheet failed' error 1004

Comment: @ChrisLafky Think about what ranges look like. Now you've made a range that looks like `Range("A:15")` if nxtRow=15

Comment: yes I see that but I do not want to specify the whole range it is pasted to just the row/first cell. How would I write that?

Comment: @ChrisLafky `Range("A15")` is the first column in row 15. If you use the `:` it means like from … to. so `Range("A15:A20")` is from cell A15 to cell A20.

Comment: You *have* to specify the entire range. Like I said, you're equalising two ranges' values. Both ranges have to be equal in size

Comment: @ChrisLafky did my answer help you? If so, please don't forget to accept it